# NSRunLoop working OK on Simulator, Crashes iDevice

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstimer, nsrunloop

I'm working on an iOS App (FW: 5.0+ & ARC) which needs to update second by second.

Currently, I have this within a method (which is called in a performSelector when -ViewDidLoad):

```
-(void)FireOnload {
counter = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(countDownTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[counter fire];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:counter forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode]; // <-- Causing Problem
}

-(void)countDownTime
{
double timeNow = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
double timeLeft = timeEnding - timeNow;

if(timeLeft < 60) // Less then 60 seconds, do something.
{
   //Do Stuff
}

}
```

the `counter` variable is called in the header as NSTimer.
I explicitly call `[counter fire]` so it is called as soon as the view is loaded, not after 1 second.

**This works fine** in the iOS Simulator and will fire every second, but when it goes to the iDevice, it crashes.

I've commented out the `NSRunLoop` line, and the iDevice does not crash. However, it no longer updates every second.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the stack trace on crash?  Also, you mention you call `FireOnload` using `performSelector` - are you calling on the main thread or background?

Comment: Well this won't fix the actual problem but if you are going to put the timer on the runloop right away, you can also use scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: and don't put it on the runloop manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the Problem:

changed:

`@property (weak, nonatomic) NSTimer *counter;`

to:

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *counter;`

If you're not using ARC, then you'll need to replace `strong` with `retain`

Answer (score 0):

You say you use `performSelector` to invoke FireOnLoad.  Why?  If you are invoking it on a background thread, you need to know that NSRunLoop is not thread safe so you shouldn't access the main runloop except on the main thread.